# R: SHINY DateRangeInput

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny

Como puedo hacer para crear un gráfico solo con aquellas filas que cumplan la  condición de que la fecha este dentro de las fechas elegidas en el `DateRangeInput`.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
     dateRangeInput(inputId = "rango", label = "Seleccione fecha", format = "yyyy-mm-dd"),
     plotOutput("nuevosBenef")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$nuevosBenef <- renderPlot({
        ggplot(Altas, aes(x = FechaAlta, y = Valor)) + geom_point()
    })
}
```

Mi data `frame` es Altas y la columna a comprar con el `dateRange` es FechaAlta.
Saludos y gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El imput de rango de fecha crea un vector con dos elementos, en formato fecha, uno con la fecha mínima y otro con la fecha másxima. Si tu data frame `Altas` tieene el objeto `FechaAlta` en formato fecha, entonces puedes aplicar el filtro que te coloco a continuación.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
     dateRangeInput(inputId = "rango", label = "Seleccione fecha", format = "yyyy-mm-dd"),
     plotOutput("nuevosBenef")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$nuevosBenef <- renderPlot({

      Altas %>%
        filter(FechaAlta >= input$rango[1], FechaAlta <= input$rango[2]) %>%
        ggplot(aes(x = FechaAlta, y = Valor)) + geom_point()
    })
}
```